# Previous part time employer never paid me but I received a W-2

Tags: united-states, form-w-2

I worked part time for a corporate company that never paid me. I received a W-2. Who do I contact? I tried to reach the manager but he won't return my calls.

Comment: Did they never pay you for valid reasons, or did they never pay you because they were sleazy/dishonest? If the latter, then you might be better off worrying about getting the money they owe you rather than about the bogus tax consequences. E.g., here in California, if an employer doesn't pay you when they owe you, you can get paid a multiple of what they should have paid. This makes this type of case attractive to employment lawyers.

Answer (score 1):

If they didn't pay you, you do not owe any tax on the W-2 income, but the IRS will be informed of the income and expect to see it on your return.

You should contact the company asap and tell them that as they didn't pay you, their filing of Form W-2 was incorrect and ask them to correct and issue you a W-2C.  They probably won't want to as it's a real pain depending on how big the Company is, but if they do, that would solve the issue.

Even if they don't, as long as you have proof that you were not paid, you are not subject to any liability with the IRS with respect to this matter as long as you can document that you never received anything from them.  You would probably get a letter from the IRS asking why the income was not reported by you and you would then send them the evidence of your not having received it and that would be that.

Comment: It is hard to prove a negative. How on earth can the OP _prove_ that he was never paid? Show the IRS the monthly statements from the bank to show that the amount was never deposited by you (or sent to the account via EFT? All that shows is that the.money was not deposited into _that_ account, not that the money was never received. Many large grocery store chains offer check-cashing services (including payroll checks) for their customers who do not have bank accounts, etc. In short, your suggested method for "prooff that you were not paid" will not work as you claim it will.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to reach the manager but he won't return my calls.

If this is a corporation, call their Human Resources (HR) department.  Or their payroll department.  Your manager probably has little to do with payroll.  This also takes some emotion out of it if you and your manager parted on bad terms.

Consider the possibility that they cut you a check that you never received.  It might be easier to get them to send you that check or a replacement than to to get the W-2 changed.  If so, try to resolve that quickly.  That route probably involves you paying the taxes as if you were paid last year.

If there are difficulties, there are additional steps that you can take.  But they depend somewhat on the circumstances of you not getting paid.  Some of them might fit better on Law.SE or Workplace.SE -- we're getting into a gray area.  My main point was that if you're dealing with someone large enough to have an HR department, that's where I'd probably start regarding this.  They can tell you the way that things seem from their perspective.

Comment: Even if it's not a corporation, call their Human Resources department or their Payroll department. There's nothing special here about being a corporation.